# Disable Admin CP authentication (or auto login)

Tags: wp-admin, login, wp-login-form

Is there a way to allow *anyone* into the admin panel, without the need to log in?

Or, if need be, is there a way to have Wordpress auto-login using a certain set of credentials?

This seems like something that should be trivial, but it appears nobody else has found a use case for this as of yet.

Comment: Oh, and *yes*, I am aware of the implications; there really *is* a valid use-case for this. I promise ;)

Comment: how is it different from simply giving user and password info? maybe there is a use case but right now it is totally not obvious

Comment: @MarkKaplun Because it's an internal tool we're using more as a CMS and less as a blog. For its particular purpose, there's no point for credentials.

Comment: "For its particular purpose, there's no point for credentials" - I am sure this is what they said at target ;). And you didn't really answered my question about why not to give user and password as public info

Comment: This is easily done.  You could create a user with a specific WP role.  Then hook into the 'authenticate' filter. In the function return the created user.  The other component is that you would need to modify the login form so that it is not a form... just a login button or login link.

Comment: @MarkKaplun It's an **internal** tool. Target's leaks were 100% different; your argument is invalid. I have a use case for this; I'm simply asking how it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is  example code that will log everyone in as 'autologinuser'.  The 'autologinuser' needs to be created and given a role prior to using this code.

```
function my_autologin() {
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        $uid = 'autologinuser';
        $user = get_userdatabylogin( $uid );
        wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID);
        wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
        do_action('wp_login', $user_login);  // optional
    }
}
add_action('init','my_autologin');
```

Comment: This doesn't bypass the login form though

Comment: That code above, should work with the WP login form.  I believe you should be able to leave the username/password fields empty and click on the submit button.  Note that there was a typo that I corrected.  I have code that modifies the login form, but it contains our css so it wouldnt be that useful.  Would you want me to show you the code, minus css?

Comment: Again, the point isn't to modify the login form but instead bypass it altogether.

Comment: Misunderstood you initially.  I updated the code now to autologin users transparently.

Comment: There we go :) That's enough to work with. Thank you!